# How to use swing font rendering system in javafx font rendering system?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, fonts

I created a lot of my projects with JavaFX 11. However, the JavaFX 11 font rendering system does not display *Myanmar Unicode* correctly. When I use Java Swing text area, *Myanmar Unicode* is displayed correctly.

So I decided to develop Java Swing font rendering system in JavaFX. But I did not know how to improve it.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*How to get Swing-looking font rendering in JavaFX?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30431591/642706)

Comment: _So I decided to develop Java Swing font rendering system in JavaFX_ that's quite an endeavour - good luck :) Did you check fx17ea or fx11 as suggested in a comment to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580355/javafx-myanmar-unicode-do-not-display-correctly ?

Comment: Thanks Bro, I am fine with Javafx 17 ea version.